# Where does a document library description appear in 2013?

Tags: 2013, document-library, learning

I wrote this document library description in 2007 but now we're on 2013 it doesn't seem to appear? Where would the users see this library description?

[image: document library settings]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be a tiny (i) like icon to the right of your library title. Click on that, and you should get the description!

Comment: Aah can't believe I didn't see that earlier! Thanks,  Much prefered how it looked in 2007, how is anyone going to find that..?

Answer (score 4):

Their are couple of ways to see the description of Document Library.

**Method # 1** For all sharepoint versions, you can go to document library settings page and you will see the description on that page. this is for all versions of SharePoint.

**Method # 2**

- For SharePoint 2007 and 2010, you can see this, once you click on the document library, the description showed under the document library. like this
  [image]
- For 2013 & 2016, it should be appear to next of Document Library if you click on "i".[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go into Library Setting >

Then form the left hand side, under General Settings (top left of the body of the page), select "List name, description and navigation"

You can now edit the "Description" field. Click Save.

Then the new description will show up on the "i" next to the Document Library name as shown from above example with highlight.